# ASP.NET EnumDropDownListFor generates the DropDown but doesn't select model's value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a big problem with my project. I have a ViewModel that has an Enum type attribute : Constants.Days Day ( Monday = 1 to Sunday = 7) that I already use in an Edit View to generate a dropdown list. The model's value is correctly selected in it. I use the EnumDropDownListFor Helper.

In an other View ( a partial view this time generated with the RenderAction helper ) I try to do the same stuff but the DropDown doesn't select model's Day. The first option is selected. I tried with a TextBoxFor and the correct Day is put inside of it. It's very strange... I tried to do a classic DropDownListFor but the result is the same. The value is available, the dropdown is generated correctly, BUT the model's Day value isn't selected in the DropDown. The Update works too.

Can anybody help me please ? Thank you very much :)

Here you can see a screenshot of the View where the Day is correctly put in a TextBox but not selected in the dropdown.

[image: Screenshot of the View with Dropdown and textbox]

**The PartialView :**

```
@model p3t.Models.ScheduledLessonViewModel

<div class="modal" id="@("updateLessonModal" + Model.ScheduledLessonId)" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateLessonModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Planifier un cours</h4>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateSchedule", "Home"))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal ">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ScheduledLessonId)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Day, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Day, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control btn btn-default col-md-10", disabled = "disabled" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mettre à jour</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**The View**

```
@model p3t.Models.ScheduleViewModel
@using p3t.Models.Dal.Dto


@foreach (var lesson in Model.ScheduledLessons)
{
   if (lesson.Section.SectionId == Model.Section.SectionId)
   {
       if (day.Equals(lesson.Day.ToString()) && lesson.BeginHour.Hours == h)
       {
           Html.RenderAction("UpdateSchedule", lesson);

          <div class="lesson">

          @if (User.IsInRole("Administrateur") || User.IsInRole("Secrétaire"))
          {
             <button id="@lesson.ScheduledLessonId" class="pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-cog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@("updateLessonModal" + lesson.ScheduledLessonId)"></button>
             <button id="" class="pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-trash"</button>
          }
       }
    }
}
```

**The Controller's Actions for the View:**

```
public ActionResult UpdateSchedule(ScheduledLessonModel model)
        {
            ScheduledLessonViewModel slvm = new ScheduledLessonViewModel();
            slvm.LessonList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            slvm.SectionList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            slvm.ClassroomList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var lessonList = lessonRepository.GetAll();
            var sectionList = sectionRepository.GetAll();
            var classroomList = classroomRepository.GetAll();

            foreach (var item in lessonList)
            { slvm.LessonList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.LessonId.ToString(), Text = item.Name }); }
            foreach (var item in sectionList)
            { slvm.SectionList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.SectionId.ToString(), Text = item.Tag }); }
            foreach (var item in classroomList)
            { slvm.ClassroomList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.ClassroomId.ToString(), Text = item.Name }); }

            slvm.ScheduledLessonId = model.ScheduledLessonId;
            slvm.Day = model.Day;
            slvm.BeginHour = model.BeginHour;
            slvm.EndHour = model.EndHour;
            slvm.Quadrimester = model.Quadrimester;
            slvm.LessonId = model.Lesson.LessonId;
            slvm.SectionId = model.Section.SectionId;
            slvm.ClassroomId = model.Classroom.ClassroomId;

            return PartialView("ScheduleModal", slvm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateSchedule(ScheduledLessonViewModel slvm)
        {
            try
            {
                ScheduledLessonModel slmodel = new ScheduledLessonModel();
                slmodel.Lesson = new LessonModel();
                slmodel.Section = new SectionModel();
                slmodel.Classroom = new ClassroomModel();

                slmodel.ScheduledLessonId = slvm.ScheduledLessonId;
                slmodel.Day = slvm.Day;
                slmodel.BeginHour = slvm.BeginHour;
                slmodel.EndHour = slvm.EndHour;
                slmodel.Quadrimester = slvm.Quadrimester;
                slmodel.Lesson.LessonId = slvm.LessonId;
                slmodel.Section.SectionId = slvm.SectionId;
                slmodel.Classroom.ClassroomId = slvm.ClassroomId;

                scheduledLessonRepository.Update(slmodel);

                return RedirectToAction("Schedule", new { sectionId = slvm.SectionId });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: show the code of view and action

Comment: Yeah I have just edited :)

Comment: Show the Schedule action

Comment: Edit your question and show only the code relevant to your question. I assume you mean the line `Html.RenderAction("UpdateSchedule", lesson);` in which case, no it wont work. You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for collection items. Use an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks I will try it ^^ I will give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In your Schedule GET action, try setting `vm.Day` to whatever value you want your drop down to have selected.

Comment: I have 2 Modals : one for Create and one for Edit. The problem is in the Edit Modal where the model's Day value isn't selected :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding. What's the value of model.Day in your view when it creates the EnumDropDownFor?